# DataServiceQuery Expanding Related Expands

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services

Assuming a `Company` has multiple `Employee`s who in turn each have multiple `AttendanceRecord`s.

Using `DataServiceQuery` I can include all employees of all companies:

```
 dataContext.Companies.Expand(c => c.Employees);
```

However, what if I want to include all employee attendance records as well?

I can't do this:

```
dataContext.Companies.Expand(c => c.Employees).Expand(ce => ce.AttendanceRecords);
```

because in the second `Expand`, I still only have Company properties available to me (thus `ce` is still referring to Companies, not "CompaniesEmployees".

Similarly, I can't do this:

```
dataContext.Companies.Expand(c => c.Employees.Expand(e => e.AttendanceRecords));
```

because the `Expand` method is not available on Employees.

How can I bring back Companies, Employees, and Attendance records in a single query?

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen Entity Framework

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this:

```
var companies = dataContext.Execute<Company>(new Uri("http://service/Companies?$expand=Employees($expand=AttendanceRecords)")).ToList();
```

Comment: OData v4 starts to support expanding entities inside another $expand.

Comment: In this case I think it would be better to use the `Expand(string)` method e.g. dataContext.Companies.Expand("Companies/Employees"), but I was really hoping for a solution using lambda expressions to take advantage of strong typing.

Comment: As far as I know, there no such method currently.